# Java multi line comments in java - what is wrong?

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line="";
        Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("(?s)\\s*(/\\*.*\\*/)",Pattern.DOTALL);
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to detect multi line comment. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the error (message/call-stack)? what is the wrong outcome? is it for a specific line of input?

Comment: *Where am I wrong?*  Using regexes for parsing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to detect multi line comment. Where am I wrong

Your regex looks fine but it has redundant `(?s)` and it won't work with nested comments. Also `.*` is greedy so it will find last `*/` rather than shortest one.

However **main problem is** use of:

```
br.readLine()
```

which is reading input line by line hence your pattern matching is not able to detect multiline comments when input to your `matcher` method is just one line.

Comment: Aren't nested comments are forbidden in Java?

Comment: By nested I mean `/* some comment /* text */ int x=1; /* more comment */`

Comment: You are a very clever person :)

Comment: Erm .... that's not what people normally mean by nesting.  This is what I understand it to mean: `/* Outer comment /* Nested comment */ rest of outer comment */`  And as Bailey says ... not supported in Java.